# How to install IonCube Loader on Amazon Linux x64 instance

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, ioncube

I'm having trouble installing IonCube Loader on my Amazon Linux x64 instance.

I'm following these instructions below but the paths are way off and I can't seem to locate the right ones on my install.

For x64:

```
wget http://downloads2.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz 
tar xfvz ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
```

Proceed as follows:

```
cp ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so /usr/lib/php5/20090626/ioncube.so
```

Now edit to match:

```
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php5/20090626/ioncube.so

nano /etc/php5/conf.d/ioncube.ini
```

First, there is no `/usr/lib/php5/20090626/` folder. I changed these paths to `/usr/lib64/php/modules` and included the .so file in there.

However, I cannot seem to locate any `ioncube.ini` file to edit. Any help is appreciated...

Thank you!

Comment: It appears you are following debian/ubuntu paths. Amazon ec2 linux is based on redhat and would store php config in /etc/php.ini and /etc/php.d/*.ini

Answer (score 1):

For future readers sake, there is a difference between Amazon's Linux and other versions that most articles online refer to.

You can follow the first two steps above to get the installer, I like to use a temporary folder. Do this as root:

```
sudo -i
cd /tmp
wget http://downloads2.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz 
tar xfvz ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
```

Copy the required extension to a slightly different folder under EC2 linux instances, and the loader wizard to your webroot:

```
cp ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube.so
```

Create your ini file:

```
echo "zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube.so" > /etc/php.d/ioncube.ini
```

Reload Apache (if you're using it):

```
service httpd restart
```

I'm using NGINX and PHP-FPM, in this case you'd probably want to restart PHP-FPM as well as NGINX.

Lastly, use the loader wizard to test it by navigating to http://example.com/loader-wizard.php, and delete the temp files and loader wizard when finished:

```
rm -rf /tmp/ioncube*
rm /var/www/html/loader-wizard.php
```

Comment: Contrary to the instructions above, `http://downloads2.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz` does **not** include `loader-wizard.php` therefore it can not be copied after extracting the tar-ball. (It may have in the past).

Comment: Also, according to the instruction manuals: `Match the Loader with your PHP version, e.g. for PHP 5.3, ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so (extensions are inside the folder)`

Comment: Happened to be going through this install process again and stumbled upon my comments from back in February - it looks like this time as at today that `loader-wizard.php` is back in `ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz` - so maybe that was a mistake on the part of Ioncube from back in February.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions provided here in the first answer, making allowance for the fact that I'm runnning PHP 5.6:

```
sudo cp ioncube_loader_lin_5.6.so /usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/ioncube.so
echo "zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/ioncube.so" > /etc/php.d/ioncube.ini
```

However, when restarting Apache, I found that it started then failed immediately. The Apache log gave me this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  [ionCube Loader] The Loader must appear as the first entry in the php.ini file in Unknown on line 0
```

I changed the name of the file from **ioncube.so** to **00-ioncube.so** and restarted Apache. This solved the problem by making this file load before the other modules.